# Parial Page Load removes data from div binded using append jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am appending data to `div` using `jquery`. It works fine. But, now if user clicks on any `asp.net` button then it removes all data from that `div`. Don't know what is the wrong. Please help me.
**HTML Part :**

```
<div id="dataHolder">
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update" onClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
var allData = "hello, this is string";
jquery("#dataHolder").append(allData );
```

I am not calling any remove method for this.

Comment: What is this `asp.net button ` probably their is a click event binded to this element. Try removing it. Or post some more code.

Comment: I think your asp.net button is making a serverside request and for this the changes which are made by js/jquery resets to it defaults.

Comment: @Jai, yes, it is making server side request. Is there anyway by which js does not reset it to defaults.

Comment: @JeetenParmar maybe you want to try using localStorage for it.